# how can I fix a removed studs, on wall in basement above stairs?

Tags: studs

I had my basement waterproofed, and some studs had to be cut to drill for the drainage pipe. They also cut the bottom plate, which I cut a piece of PT wood and set it in place where the section was removed.

I can't remove the existing cut studs, because the drywall behind it is attached to them.  The stringers are secured to the basement ground, and one stringer attached to the brick wall on other side, I think the studs might attach to them also, but I'm not 100% sure.

How do I make this to code?  Or ... if not possible any longer, how do I make this structurally strong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Almost anyway you want for a non load bearing wall.  Studs there are mostly for nailing/screwing wall covering to.  The stud on the left side shows one way, but I like more surface.  I would try to mark(pencil, tape) the floor and/or ceiling if the studs are sifted over.  Nothing worst than screwing drywall to a stud and half way down find the stud missing.  Load bearing wall studs do need specific ways of repair and probably need an engineer before and after.

Comment: I don't think it's bearing load, could I just sister in a stud next to the second cut stud from the left?  then call it good?

Comment: Non load bearing can do almost anything, sistering probably the easiest.  Someway to remember where studs change places would help in future.  Expecting a stud at 16 OC but is at 18 OC is nice to know for nailing/screwing.

Comment: why would you want to replace them if as you say they are not needed for the structure, if for drywall you can use horizontal studs

Comment: So I see from the edit you deleted the load bearing part in the title. Are you sure this isn't a load bearing wall? If it isn't load bearing, fixing is easy. If it is load bearing, you really want to add studs where they were cut.

Comment: It's not load bearing for the house, but the stringers are fastened to to some of the studs.  I just sistered the second cut stud from the left, seems much better to me this way.... I don't know what that first stud, that is two pieces in differing places, really was adding anyway.

Comment: Could you get us a better focused and lit picture of the wall, please. Also, include more of the top of the studs and what they're supporting. It does appear that these studs are simply there to hang the drywall from, but I wouldn't want to commit to that statement. If it _is_ a load bearing wall, your waterproofing contractor should be shot for just cutting up a load bearing wall like that, then held responsible for a proper replacement/repair.

Comment: @FreeMan I'll take some more pictures, I'm pretty sure it's not load baring because the wall was not present at the time the house was built in 1921.   I can tell by the studs, which are all in post 1964 sizes, my guess it that it was built sometime after mid 80s.  A door was added to the basement entry, which was why the wall was initially built, but i removed it.  It's not load bearing for the house.

Comment: @FreeMan, OK I've taken more pictures with light and even one looking down on the stairs.  The drywall is the white colored wall in that picture.  I don't believe it's load bearing for the house,... but there could have been a prior wall, that got rotted out, and was replaced.  I also sistered a stud in place, which you'll now see in the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It meets code as is. It's not habitable space, so it doesn't require an outlet. It's not a fire wall, so it doesn't even need drywall. It doesn't support the house nor the staircase. (load bearing walls generally don't run the same direction as the joists... and no stringer ever counts on the wall next to it to do anything)

It can exist as is, or completely not be, with both an outlet and drywall being optional.

Cut the rest of the studs out, drywall the wall and the underside of the staircase. Now you can put crap there, and there isn't a **mystery zone** of, *I wonder what's happening under there after that last flood we had....*

Comment: The staircase in my modern house relies on the walls immediately adjacent.  The engineer even wanted to see the nails penetrating through the walls to ensure the proper length nails were used.